# ngRepeat: dupes ERROR on simple JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I may be missing something obvious here but I think this should simply loop through my provided JSON. However, I get the ngRepeat:dupes error that says that uid is undefined. If I don't track by ID I get the duplicate error. It seems that the string is being treated not as JSON but a simple string even though I am parsing in my controller. What am I missing here?

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in monresults track by item.uid">
    <td>{{item.date}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td><a href="{{item.url}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm btn-block">Play Call <i class="fa fa-volume-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

My JSON looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "uid":"2",
      "name":"Saturday 8-5",
      "url":"http://example.com/calls/sat-8-5-17.mp3",
      "cs4000id":"hea654hdf!iDk1sjPz8dsa",
      "date":"08-05-17",
      "created":"2017-08-21 09:44:16",
      "emp":""
   },
   {
      "uid":"3",
      "name":"Saturday 8-12",
      "url":"http://example.com/calls/sat-8-12-17.mp3",
      "cs4000id":"5PR$NTuMbFq8x!k1sjPz86Nk",
      "date":"08-12-17",
      "created":"2017-08-21 09:45:06",
      "emp":""
   }
]
```

Here is monresults in my CTRL and I'm logging the the results to make sure it looks right:

```
    Data.get('moncall').then(function (results) {
    $scope.monresults = JSON.parse(results);
    console.log($scope.monresults);
});
```

Comment: Does the code work when you set `$scope.monresults` manually to the data you've posted?

Comment: Why not use `track by $index`?

Comment: If I 'track by $index' my view repeats out as if by EACH character of the array. (you'll notice that my JSON is objects in an array). It will give me a 50+ empty rows. Very strange.

Comment: Ok, @nadavvadan I set the $scope directly to the Json and everything worked properly. Any idea on why my `JSON.parse(results);` looks good by the eye test when logging to console or just simply printing to screen. Though is not treated like an actual JSON object?

Comment: You keep confusing `JSON`, which is a `String` containing a JS-Object-like structure, and actual JS `object`s, which are a separate data type.

Your issue might arise from the asynchronous nature of your code; Does it say `uid is not defined` or something like `cannot get property uid of undefined`?

Comment: You are right, my confusion. Here is what I get: `Repeater: item in monresults track by item.uid, Duplicate key: undefined, Duplicate value: {2}` To clarify, everything works when i assign the scope variable directly to the array of objects. It doesn't work when assigned to the parsed call referenced in my original code.

Comment: i think the problem is how do your recive in results the data.. if you recive something like `"[{item:"value"},{item:"value2"}]"; ` it need JSON.parse() but if you receive `[{item:"value"},{item:"value2"}]` without the quotes, dont need JSON.parse.

Comment: I guess you are getting JSON in correct format and you don't need to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up mistakenly double encoding the JSON response - thanks